# Proof that a linear code union/intersect with another linear code is a linear code

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

> Let $C$ be a binary linear code and $\neg C := \{\neg c$ $|$ $  c$ $ 
>  \epsilon$ $ C\ \}$. $\neg c$ is the complement of $c$. So for $c =
>  c_1,...,c_n $ with $c_i \  \epsilon \ \{0,1\}$ the complement is $\neg
>  c_i \ = c_i \oplus1 $.

Tasks:

1. Proof that:

> If $1^n \ \epsilon \ C$ then  $ C = \neg C $.

2. Proof or disproof:

> If $C$ is linear, then $\neg C$ is linear.

3. Proof or disproof:

> If $C$ is linear, then $C \cap \neg C $ is linear.

4. Proof or disproof:

> If $C$ is linear, then $C \cup \neg C $ is linear.

My question: 
How to do this proof? The wiki article about linear codes isn't very helpful for me.

This is homework, so i would like to get hints (e.g. a way to do the proof) rather then a full solution to work it out myself.

Comment: You should start by writing the definition of a "linear code," which can then be used to solve each of those problems.  You should also identify exactly what you need to show, i.e., for problem 1, "Fix $c \in C$. We want to show that..."

Comment: I want to try the problem D) cause i try to understand this proofs too: $C ∪ \neg C <=> C ∪ (C+1^n) $ with $c_1,c_2 \in C $ then $c_1+c_2 \in C$ this is correct because $C$ is a linear code $(c_1+1^n) + (c_2 + 1^n) = c_1 + c_2 + 1^n +1^n = c_1 + c_2$ this is correct because $1^n+1^n mod 2 = 0$ Therefore $C ∪ \neg C$ is linear. Is this proof sufficient? I guess i can show scalar multiplaction, too.. But do i need it if it is a linear code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A)

Since $C$ is a binary linear code, for any $c_1,c_2\in C$ we have $c_1+c_2\in C$. Since $1^n\in C$ therefore for any $c\in C$ also $c+1^n\in C$ where $\neg c=c+1^n\in C$ and this holds for all $c\in C$ so $\neg C=C$.

> B)

This one doesn't hold e.g. take $C=\{(0,0),(0,1)\}$ as a linear codebook, therefore $\neg C=\{(1,1),(1,0)\}$ which is not linear since $(1,1)+(1,0)=(0,1)\notin \neg C$.

> C)

this is true only if $\neg C$ is a linear codebook. In that case, for $c_1,c_2\in C\cap \neg C$ we have $c_1,c_2\in C$ and $c_1,c_2\in\neg C$. Since both $C$ and $\neg C$ are linear  we have $c_1+c_2\in C$ and $c_1+c_2\in\neg C$ or $c_1+c_2\in C\cap\neg C$. Therefore $C\cap\neg C$ is linear.

> D)

$C\cup \neg C$ is linear only if $\neg C$ is linear (why?)

Comment: So the only thing i have to show is that $ \forall \ x, \ y \ \epsilon \ C \ : \ x+y \ \epsilon \ C  $ ? What about scalar multiplication?

Comment: since the problem is binary then all the calculations are modulo 2